# Limite de requisições HTTP e consultas SQL

Tags: mysql, http, servidor, requisição, requisitos

estou desenvolvendo um sistema que terá uma grande quantidade de requisições e gostaria de saber a opinião com base na experiência de vocês.

1) Um servidor rodando apache com php e 64GB de memória, processaria 50.000 requisições por segundo? Exemplo, uma requisição HTTP por GET retornado um 'Hello world em texto'.

2) Essa mesma requisição faria um UPDATE num servidor rodando somente o MySQL, o MySQL suportaria 50.000 queries por segundo?

Minha dúvida é bem genérica, espero que tenha fornecido informações suficientes para uma opinião. Ou senão, que configuração seria necessária para suportar 50k requisições ou mais?

Comment: Processar 50K simultaneamente em MariaDB numa instancia única e num servidor compartilhado com o PHP é impossível, literalmente. Um servidor  ÚNICO e exclusivo para MariaDB com 64GB de RAM e um CPU razoável (2x E5-2620) pode suportar 1000~5000 requisições simultaneas, logo dependerá do tempo que cada um demora, mas isso depende da complexidade da query e do que ela pode usar, por exemplo do `read_buffer_size`, `sort_buffer_size`, `join_buffer_size`, `read_rnd_buffer_size`... Fora o uso de CPU e taxa de leitura/gravação no disco.... Se for ter 50K simultâneos só com várias replicas.

Answer (score 2):

Bom, vamos lá!

## Memória, processador ou disco não é tudo

Quando tratamos de infraestrutura, ter um processador forte, uma unidade de disco com E/S alta ou até 64gb de memória pode não significar suporte a grandes requisições por segundo. Você precisa analisar tudo por questão de escala.

## Banco de dados

MySQL talvez não seja o mais recomendável para você, você pode optar por bancos NoSQL, que irá melhorar sua performance muito mais. Também é interessante estudar [`cluster`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-cluster-overview.html) que divide as cargas, trabalhar com diversos `nodes`.

Estude implementação por exemplo de `Redis`, `Elasticsearch`, `MongoDB` e etc. Cada engine tem uma proposta que trabalha melhor com questões específicas, estude seu caso.

## PHP

Eu sou desenvolver PHP, mas coloco em cheque-mate com uma questão: PHP é a melhor linguagem para este objetivo de grandes requisições? Já estudou outras abordagens? Qual é o objetivo? Qual resultado esperado?

## Escale and not-shared

Primeiro, você precisa entender o que é [`load balancer`](https://www.citrix.com/glossary/load-balancing.html) e como ele poderá te ajudar com a alta escala de servidores que você precisará provisionar.

Sua infraestrutura deverá ser toda interdependente e ter planejamento de falhas.

### Para finalizar

Sua pergunta é pouco genérica demais, já que perguntar se x ou y linguagem aguenta x ou y requisições por segundos sobre x ou y condições é grande demais, não é tão simples assim infraestrutura. Hoje em dias existem diversas tecnologias que podem abstrair maiores responsabilidade com menores custos, por exemplo `Docker`. Se você tem em suas mãos o desenvolvimento de um sistema que irá receber essa carga, o interessante é você procurar pessoas responsáveis por suas respectivas áreas como: Banco de Dados, Infraestrutura e gerente de projeto. Muitos detalhes serão levados em consideração, para só assim você conseguir construir uma infraestrutura escalável, barata e acima de tudo, forte :)